# Lazarus on Windows: Why the extra terminal window?

Tags: windows, terminal, lazarus

I built a Lazarus GUI application using Ubuntu and then took it onto Windows to compile. On Ubuntu I run it from the terminal like this:

```
./prg arg
```

It runs fine using the argument **arg** passed to it. On Windows this is what I did:

1. Create shortcut to exe
2. Edit shortcut and include the argument.

To run on Windows, I run the shortcut.

It works fine but there's an additional terminal window opening behind the application, when I run the shortcut. When the application exits, the window closes with it. The terminal window is empty.

On Windows, before compiling I had to uncheck the **-WG** switch in compiler options. This was because althought the app is GUI-based, there is a simple routine that checks for the argument passed at command line and uses Writeln to output a message if there were errors.

My key question is why is this terminal window coming up on Windows and how do I get rid of it or suppress it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(1) Make sure you have set {$APPTYPE GUI} in your code. Otherwise there will be always a "terminal" opened on windows.
(2) Maybe you are confusing a "real" shortcut (*.lnk) with cmd/batch file? The latter also opens a terminal that dies when the lauched app closes.